# Round table seating probability with 8 people

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Mr. A, Mr. B and $6$ more people wants to sit around round table. We need to find out the probability that Mr. A and Mr. B will sit near each other. First of all we need to describe $(Ω,F,P)$

I think n=(8−7)!=5040 than Mr. A and Mr. B we can keep as one because we want them to sit near each other. Tham m=(7−1)!∗2=1440 Than P=m/n=1440/5040=2/7 Is ir right?

And how I should describe (Ω,F,P)?

Comment: Something I really dislike about these kind of questions, just because the only measure you have is "seating positions are uniformly sampled" doesn't mean thats the "truth". Now Mr A and Mr B don't exist, but if they did their seating probabilities wouldn't be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

You can get 2/7 directly.  Seat A anywhere, then there are 2 out of 7 places for B to be next to A.